# Why is my category "vanishing" from the navigation menu after a period of time?

Tags: products, link

Let's say I open my product page and now I got following structure:

`home -> category_x -> product_y`

I think this is the normal case which we all knew. But after sometimes if I let the page open it will change to this:

`home -> product_y`

What is happening here and how could I prevent this?

Comment: Do you have the configuration `Use categories path for product URL’s` set to `yes` ?

Comment: No! This seems very logical. I will test it and maybe it will fix it. Thank you.

Comment: OK no problem. I put this in an answer post to your quesiton ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell Magento to use categories `url_key` in your product URLs in `System > Configuration > Catalog > SEO > Use Categories Path for Product URLs` and set this option to `Yes`
**Note** : Take care with this option to the duplicate content of your product page